# Aspose.Words mixed RowFormat.Borders.Horizontal.LineStyle

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

We're having trouble creating a table with mixed `RowFormat.Borders.Horizontal.LineStyle`. Our requirement is to have the following (notice the black solid line):

[image]

The closest we got is this:

[image]

We’ve tried various things but can’t seem to get the desired table.

Below is a sample code of what we have so far…

```
using Aspose.Words;
using Aspose.Words.Tables;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

---

```
int i = 1;
var doc = new Document();
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.StartTable();

builder.RowFormat.Borders.Horizontal.LineStyle = LineStyle.Dot;

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCell("merge 1");
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None; //reset

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCellAuto();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None; //reset

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCell("merge 2");
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None; //reset

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCellAuto();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.EndRow();

builder.EndTable();

string fileName = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")}.docx";
doc.Save(fileName);
Process.Start(fileName);

void InsertCellAuto() => InsertCell(i++.ToString());

void InsertCell(string text)
{
    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Writeln(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can meet this requirement by using the following code:

```
int i = 1;
var doc = new Document();
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

Table tab = builder.StartTable();           

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCell("merge 1");
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None; //reset

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCellAuto();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None; //reset

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCell("merge 2");
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None; //reset

InsertCellAuto();
InsertCellAuto();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.EndRow();

builder.EndTable();

// Apply Dotted line styles to all Rows
foreach (Row r in tab.Rows)
{
    r.RowFormat.Borders.Horizontal.LineStyle = LineStyle.Dot;
}
// Apply Single line styles to a particular Row
Row row = tab.Rows[1];
foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
{
    cell.CellFormat.Borders[BorderType.Bottom].LineStyle = LineStyle.Single;
}

doc.Save("D:\\temp\\18.10.docx");

void InsertCellAuto() => InsertCell(i++.ToString());

void InsertCell(string text)
{
    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Writeln(text);
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: works like a charm! thank you!
quick question, our requirement can only be achieved by modifying the format after `EndTable`, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is better to apply formatting to cells and rows after EndTable (completing the table).

Comment: You mean we also move the `CellFormat.VerticalMerge`and the `RowFormat.Borders.Horizontal.LineStyle = LineStyle.Dot` after the `EndTable`?

Comment: There is no problem when using `CellFormat.VerticalMerge` and `CellFormat.HorizontalMerge` properties between `StartTable` and `EndTable`. However, you can take out the `LineStyle.Dot`. Please check, I have updated [my code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52826184/4952051).

Comment: I see. Thanks Awais!